# making certain elements visible in a viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interaction

I have specific navigational task to accomplish using css/js and right now im trying to figure out the best way to do this.

It goes like this (see image):
[image: Viewport]

As you can see there are cards displaying information (red and green). There are arrows to move the cards left or right.
So what I am trying to figure out is the following:

1) Depending on the persons browser/screen size, I need to decide how many red cards to show (2-4 max). Does anyone have any advice on how to do that?

2) I need to hide the rest of the cards either to the right (barely visible) or they are to the left. How would I best arrange the elements (divs)?

Comment: Assign a class to the left and right visible cards to add a left and right margin respectively.  So whatever card is sitting in say, the 3rd area, has a right margin that pushes the next card way off to the right.

Comment: Was the answer I provided below sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to know the width of the page, and the width of the elements you would like at the edge.
Using javascript you could align these items dynamically.

- The left item would be aligned left: 0 - item width + offset.
- The right item would be aligned right: 0 + item width - offset.

With the offset being how much of the element you would like to be visible.

This can be coupled with jQuery `.animate()` method to create a sliding effect on the element on-hover and on-click.

Here is an example of a similar effect I did a few years ago: http://www.scottycameron.com/tour/victories.aspx (click on the arrows, dates, and items).